# Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

My simple UIHostingController code gives

> Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'SwiftUI.UIHostingController' error.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
          Text("annen")
            .font(.headline)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
    }
}

class SwiftUIViewController: UIHostingController<SwiftUIView> {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: SwiftUIView())
    }
}
```

This is my extension. In SceneDelegate, its

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
      let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

      let mainView = HomeView(vm: HomeView.VM(state: self.state)).environmentObject(self.state)
      window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: mainView)
      self.window = window
      window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

I don't have any other usage of UIHostingController than this code, is this a bug or my mistake?

Comment: This question has not improved and still cannot be answered. Adding a bounty doesn't magically improve the question! You still have not given enough information for us to _reproduce the issue_. I can take your code, stick it in a UIKit Storyboard project, put your view controller into the storyboard, run the app, and segue to your view controller; the SwiftUIView appears just fine. So there is something going on that you have not told us about. If you don't tell us about it, the question cannot be answered and you are just throwing away 50 points of rep for no reason.

Comment: Hi @matt, the problem is, I don't have any other related code. This was just my extension, if you can tell me where and what I should do, I will help you. I also added the function in the SceneDelegate file to post.

Comment: OK, so this is the first time you've revealed that you are saying `window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: mainView)`. So there _is_ more code. Tell us what it is! In particular, tell us _how to crash_. You need to provide a [mcve] — that is, enough code so we can copy it, paste it into a project, run the project, do what you do, and crash as you do.

Comment: Where is the SceneDelegate code being called?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the designated initializer for UIHostingController and call super.init(rootView:) with your root view.

```
class SwiftUIViewController: UIHostingController<SwiftUIView> {

    init() {
        super.init(rootView: SwiftUIView())
    }

    @objc required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```